# Broken symbolic link

Tags: shell, csh

I have used sch script and got his

```
milenko@milenko-X58-USB3:~/Distr70_linux/Projects/Tutorial_Ex3/Run02$ ls -lia syn_stat.in 
58068654 lrwxrwxrwx 1 milenko milenko 21 Dez 23 15:22 syn_stat.in -> ../Data01/syn_stat.in
```

File properties

```
Link (broken) (inode/symlink)
```

I am copying relevant part of the csh script

```
\cp syn1.par syn.par
\rm syn_src.in syn_stat.in syn_tt.in
\cp ../Data01/syn_src.in syn_src.in
\ln -s ../Data01/syn_stat.in syn_stat.in
\cp ../Run01_syn/syn_tt.in syn_tt.in
\cp syn_src.in src_0

#Station files

set stnf = `awk '{print $9}' syn_stat.in`
```

I am on Ubuntu 14.04.What should I change to get the proper sym link?

Comment: Remove the backslashes?

Comment: It looks like you have the link you want, but the file you are linking to does not exist.